# glyphicons icons not get suitable for chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Below is the chrome view of my page. here image/icon sides not show well

[image: image 1]

But i make mouse-over/hover on that image/link  or change window width manually, its display correctly like below. but its work fine in Firefox

[image: image 2]

this is the html code i using

```
<li><a class="glyphicons display" href=""><i></i>Dashboard</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with chrome instead use another icon font  like Fontawesome
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Fontawesome is compatible with all browsers above IE7.
Fontawesome has a lot of cool icons. and it's fairly new.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

for the icons you need look at:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/cogs/

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/desktop/

You can then use them like this: `<i class="icon-desktop"></i> icon-desktop` etc.

Comment: If you put the icons in a link (I see you did) then you can just give that link a color and the icon will get the same color as your text.

Comment: So white text = white icon. blue text = blue icon. Because it's a font you can just change the color by doing something like color: #999;