# Fonts Not Properly Shown on Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, webfonts

I have this weird problem with Chrome. I use Bootstrap with its glyphicons and another font (BYekan) included using @font-face.

But sometimes the glyphicons and BYekan fonts appear as they should do, and sometimes an square appears instead of those fonts and as soon as I hover the mouse over the square, the correct form of glyphicons and my font BYekan appear.

I'm referring to a nearly exact copy of my question though with illustration ([glyphicons icons not get suitable for chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837859/glyphicons-icons-not-get-suitable-for-chrome)) which I think does not have a suitable answer.

I'm using Chrome version 32 On a Windows machine.
In addition I'm using the popular Flat UI which is based on Bootstrap and the same issue applies to its web font icons too.

I think this issue is shaking my design and I'm really concerned. I wanna be clear that dismissing Flat UI or BYekan font is OFF the table and not a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've also experienced this issue on Bootstrap-powered sites (Twitter being a notable example). This is very likely related to [a known Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298). It is reported to be fixed and the fix is expected to be shipped with Chrome 33.

Comment: All I know is that Version 33.0.1750.46 beta-m breaks Google fonts rendering.

Comment: @ZenMaster So you're saying that this issue with fonts is covered in Chrome Version 33? I'm very concerned because my application is dependent on these fonts. And could you make an estimate of release of this version?

Comment: @FighterJet 1. I am not a part of Chrome development. 2. The version I mention above breaks rendering **quality**, not the initial complaint. It seems to me that while 33 may have fixed a different issue, one of the latest updates broke rendering **quality**

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

If you don't set `font-size` for your texts, the default font size is `1em`. And apparently Chrome has problems with this font size for some fonts!

So just set your `font-size` something else (for example `font-size: 1.001em`) and your fonts will be shown correctly :)